# iOS picker view as default input method

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uipickerview

I have labelA in my custom tableview cell. When I click on the label I want picker view to be shown in the bottom of the screen in order to choose available options.

My question is: Do I actually need drag and drop `PickerView` into my view in storyboard or I can just invoke it as default input method? (Same as keyboard for text field)

If yes, how do I do that? - All I want when label is clicked show picker and hide it on when selection is finished. Could you please provide me some examples?

I am developing under swift but iOS example is fine as well.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit:**
Well label is not principle, I can use just input trigger from the cell directly. Idea after click show picker view and hide it after selection.

Comment: Label's don't support input. You will have to add all of your own code to handle a tap gesture on the label and present a picker view yourself.

Comment: @rmaddy Well label is not principle, I can use just input trigger from the cell directly. Idea after click show picker view and hide it after selection.

Answer (score 3):

What I mostly do is use a UITextField and set the inputAccessoryView property to an instance of UIPickerView. This will display the UIPickerView once you tap on the UITextField instead of the default keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate the UIPickerView all in code in your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. You can either add it to your view controller using self.view addSubView. You will have to write code to place it properly on the screen with your table view. You might want to resize your table view so it shrinks and your picker view is shown on the bottom of your view.

An easier way could be to show a modal dialog with your UIPickerView already set up.

UPDATE
Create an new controller that is of type UIViewController. 
Drag a UIViewController onto your storyboard and give it the type of the above controller and a storyboard id. I use the name of the UIViewController created.
Add your picker view to that and configure your data source.
Create a delegate for the option selected and have it return the item selected.
 - (void)selectionMade:(NSString *)selectedValue;

In your table view controller, implement that delegate method above.
In tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath, load that view controller and show it.
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@""]
Your delegate method will get that value and you can retrieve the cell using tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.
Update you cell accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I am surprised that it is so complicated and I do need adjust picker in my view on my own and it is not handled automatically. Right, could you please give me a little bit more information about the easiest way you described. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer for you